# create a dataframe grouped by column value to produce new output

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, group-by

I have a data frame that I would like to modify shown below

`data <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), Assay = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B"), Genotype = c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "AA", "BB", "CC", "AA", "BB"))`

```
   ID Assay Genotype
1   1     A       AA
2   1     B       BB
3   1     C       CC
4   1     D       DD
5   1     E       EE
6   2     A       AA
7   2     B       BB
8   2     C       CC
9   3     A       AA
10  3     B       BB
```

and I would like to take the Assay column and change that to the columns, where each ID is a row and then the genotype for each Assay, respectively. if there was no genotype for that Assay, then fill with NA values.

`output <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3), A = c("AA", "AA", "AA"), B = c("BB", "BB", "BB"), C = c("CC", "CC", "NA"), D = c("DD", "NA", "NA"), E = c("EE", "NA", "NA"))`

```
  ID  A  B  C  D  E
1  1 AA BB CC DD EE
2  2 AA BB CC NA NA
3  3 AA BB NA NA NA
```